# How can i group xaml styles into a tree structure for easy selection?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have several styles in one file. When am to apply a particular style to a control, i have to scroll through several names to get to the one of my choice.
Am currently using vs 2017. 
If am to apply a custom style, i select the control, click on style in the  properties panel, i then select local resource  which in turn displays a long list of my custom styles in the several files of my resources.
How can i group the styles , for example texblock styles , text box styles, such that have to look through the long list?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't get that type of grouping in these lists. They simply list all available resources.